incrementing file names in zsh
I am trying to write a script in zsh (Linux Mint 21.3 "Virginia") to move (or copy) a file from $source to $target with confusing results. I'm using yad file dialogs to select the files and name the target directory. The best I have been able to accomplish is copying only the final choice to the empty target.
Here is the entire script

setopt -x
setopt -v
autoload -Uz zmv

# WARNING Just because two or more files from different sources have identical names does not mean 
#that the files are identical.


declare -a array
array=$(yad --width=600 --height=800 \
--title="Choose files to move." \
--file --multiple --separator='\n') 
echo $array

target=$(yad --width=600 --height=800 \
--title="Choose destination." \
--file --directory)
echo "target="$target

# The file you wish to move may already exist in the target directory. 
# If you do not want to overwrite it you can use
# mv -n
# mv --no-clobber
# or 
# mv --backup=numbered
# Clumsy, but better than nothing, and doesn't give me what I want.
# That is why I wrote this script, it adds an incremented number to the name.
# eg <movie>.<ext>
# eg <movie>_copy1.<ext>
# eg <movie>_copy2.<ext>
# Yes, I could use brackets but they are illegal characters and I have a renamer
# that would remove them.

# You can't just use <filename>.$ext to check if the file exists in target because
# you'll miss any existing copies. You have to account for iteration.
for filename in $array; do
unset x
# decompose filename
# just name without path 
filename=$filename:t
echo
echo
echo "filename="$filename
echo
echo
# name without extension
shortname=${filename%.*}
echo "shortname="$shortname
echo
echo
# extension
ext=${filename##*.}
echo
echo
echo "ext="$ext

# The key here is to rename the file (if necessary) BEFORE copying it to target instead 
# of after.
#   Does file already exist in $target? Count them.
x=$(find $target -iname "$shortname*.$ext" | wc -c)
echo
echo
echo "x="$x

# If no file exists, move to target.
# If one file exists then $x will return "1". Think of it as
# <filename>_copy0.<ext>,
# this makes the file you wish to move
# <filename>_copy1.<ext>, - the value of $x.

case $x in
    0) cp $filename $target
    sleep .2
    ;;
    *) mv $filename $shortname_copy$x.$ext
    cp $filename $target
    sleep .2
    ;;
esac
    done
    exit 0


Here is the terminal output from two runs of the script using the same parameters.
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:4> setopt -v
autoload -Uz zmv
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:5> autoload -Uz zmv

# WARNING Just because two or more files from different sources have identical names does not mean 
#that the files are identical.


declare -a array
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:11> declare -a array
array=$(yad --width=600 --height=800 \
--title="Choose files to move." \
--file --multiple --separator='\n') 
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:12> array=+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:12> yad '--width=600' '--height=800' '--title=Choose files to move.' --file --multiple '--separator=\n'

(yad:3962282): dbind-WARNING **: 15:34:42.076: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /root/.cache/at-spi/bus_0.0: Permission denied
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:12> array=$'/home/revision-6/Videos/betty_boop_a_song_a_day_1936.mkv\n/home/revision-6/Videos/betty_boop_is_my_palm_read_1932.mkv\n/home/revision-6/Videos/betty_boop_more_pep_1936.mkv' 
echo $array
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:15> echo $'/home/revision-6/Videos/betty_boop_a_song_a_day_1936.mkv\n/home/revision-6/Videos/betty_boop_is_my_palm_read_1932.mkv\n/home/revision-6/Videos/betty_boop_more_pep_1936.mkv'
/home/revision-6/Videos/betty_boop_a_song_a_day_1936.mkv
/home/revision-6/Videos/betty_boop_is_my_palm_read_1932.mkv
/home/revision-6/Videos/betty_boop_more_pep_1936.mkv

target=$(yad --width=600 --height=800 \
--title="Choose destination." \
--file --directory)
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:17> target=+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:17> yad '--width=600' '--height=800' '--title=Choose destination.' --file --directory

(yad:3962312): dbind-WARNING **: 15:34:54.949: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /root/.cache/at-spi/bus_0.0: Permission denied
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:17> target=/home/revision-6/video_processing 
echo "target="$target
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:20> echo 'target=/home/revision-6/video_processing'
target=/home/revision-6/video_processing

# The file you wish to move may already exist in the target directory. 
# If you do not want to overwrite it you can use
# mv -n
# mv --no-clobber
# or 
# mv --backup=numbered
# Clumsy, but better than nothing, and doesn't give me what I want.
# That is why I wrote this script, it adds an incremented number to the name.
# eg <movie>.<ext>
# eg <movie>_copy1.<ext>
# eg <movie>_copy2.<ext>
# Yes, I could use brackets but they are illegal characters and I have a renamer
# that would remove them.

# You can't just use <filename>.$ext to check if the file exists in target because
# you'll miss any existing copies. You have to account for iteration.
for filename in $array; do
unset x
# decompose filename
# just name without path 
filename=$filename:t
echo
echo
echo "filename="$filename
echo
echo
# name without extension
shortname=${filename%.*}
echo "shortname="$shortname
echo
echo
# extension
ext=${filename##*.}
echo
echo
echo "ext="$ext

# The key here is to rename the file (if necessary) BEFORE copying it to target instead 
# of after.
#   Does file already exist in $target? Count them.
x=$(find $target -iname "$shortname*.$ext" | wc -c)
echo
echo
echo "x="$x

# If no file exists, move to target.
# If one file exists then $x will return "1". Think of it as
# <filename>_copy0.<ext>,
# this makes the file you wish to move
# <filename>_copy1.<ext>, - the value of $x.

case $x in
    0) cp $filename $target
    sleep .2
    ;;
    *) mv $filename $shortname_copy$x.$ext
    cp $filename $target
    sleep .2
    ;;
esac
    done
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:38> filename=/home/revision-6/Videos/betty_boop_a_song_a_day_1936.mkv
/home/revision-6/Videos/betty_boop_is_my_palm_read_1932.mkv
/home/revision-6/Videos/betty_boop_more_pep_1936.mkv
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:39> unset x
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:42> filename=betty_boop_more_pep_1936.mkv 
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:43> echo

+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:44> echo

+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:45> echo 'filename=betty_boop_more_pep_1936.mkv'
filename=betty_boop_more_pep_1936.mkv
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:46> echo

+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:47> echo

+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:49> shortname=betty_boop_more_pep_1936 
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:50> echo 'shortname=betty_boop_more_pep_1936'
shortname=betty_boop_more_pep_1936
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:51> echo

+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:52> echo

+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:54> ext=mkv 
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:55> echo

+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:56> echo

+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:57> echo 'ext=mkv'
ext=mkv
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:62> x=+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:62> find /home/revision-6/video_processing -iname 'betty_boop_more_pep_1936*.mkv'
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:62> x=+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:62> wc -c
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:62> x=0 
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:63> echo

+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:64> echo

+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:65> echo 'x=0'
x=0
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:73> case 0 (0)
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:74> cp betty_boop_more_pep_1936.mkv /home/revision-6/video_processing
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:75> sleep .2
    exit 0
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:83> exit 0
revision-6@revision6-NYI3 ~/Videos
 % cpi
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:4> setopt -v
autoload -Uz zmv
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:5> autoload -Uz zmv

# WARNING Just because two or more files from different sources have identical names does not mean 
#that the files are identical.


declare -a array
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:11> declare -a array
array=$(yad --width=600 --height=800 \
--title="Choose files to move." \
--file --multiple --separator='\n') 
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:12> array=+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:12> yad '--width=600' '--height=800' '--title=Choose files to move.' --file --multiple '--separator=\n'

(yad:3962420): dbind-WARNING **: 15:35:35.029: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /root/.cache/at-spi/bus_0.0: Permission denied
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:12> array=$'/home/revision-6/Videos/betty_boop_a_song_a_day_1936.mkv\n/home/revision-6/Videos/betty_boop_is_my_palm_read_1932.mkv\n/home/revision-6/Videos/betty_boop_more_pep_1936.mkv' 
echo $array
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:15> echo $'/home/revision-6/Videos/betty_boop_a_song_a_day_1936.mkv\n/home/revision-6/Videos/betty_boop_is_my_palm_read_1932.mkv\n/home/revision-6/Videos/betty_boop_more_pep_1936.mkv'
/home/revision-6/Videos/betty_boop_a_song_a_day_1936.mkv
/home/revision-6/Videos/betty_boop_is_my_palm_read_1932.mkv
/home/revision-6/Videos/betty_boop_more_pep_1936.mkv

target=$(yad --width=600 --height=800 \
--title="Choose destination." \
--file --directory)
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:17> target=+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:17> yad '--width=600' '--height=800' '--title=Choose destination.' --file --directory

(yad:3962450): dbind-WARNING **: 15:35:43.654: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /root/.cache/at-spi/bus_0.0: Permission denied
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:17> target=/home/revision-6/video_processing 
echo "target="$target
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:20> echo 'target=/home/revision-6/video_processing'
target=/home/revision-6/video_processing

# The file you wish to move may already exist in the target directory. 
# If you do not want to overwrite it you can use
# mv -n
# mv --no-clobber
# or 
# mv --backup=numbered
# Clumsy, but better than nothing, and doesn't give me what I want.
# That is why I wrote this script, it adds an incremented number to the name.
# eg <movie>.<ext>
# eg <movie>_copy1.<ext>
# eg <movie>_copy2.<ext>
# Yes, I could use brackets but they are illegal characters and I have a renamer
# that would remove them.

# You can't just use <filename>.$ext to check if the file exists in target because
# you'll miss any existing copies. You have to account for iteration.
for filename in $array; do
unset x
# decompose filename
# just name without path 
filename=$filename:t
echo
echo
echo "filename="$filename
echo
echo
# name without extension
shortname=${filename%.*}
echo "shortname="$shortname
echo
echo
# extension
ext=${filename##*.}
echo
echo
echo "ext="$ext

# The key here is to rename the file (if necessary) BEFORE copying it to target instead 
# of after.
#   Does file already exist in $target? Count them.
x=$(find $target -iname "$shortname*.$ext" | wc -c)
echo
echo
echo "x="$x

# If no file exists, move to target.
# If one file exists then $x will return "1". Think of it as
# <filename>_copy0.<ext>,
# this makes the file you wish to move
# <filename>_copy1.<ext>, - the value of $x.

case $x in
    0) cp $filename $target
    sleep .2
    ;;
    *) mv $filename $shortname_copy$x.$ext
    cp $filename $target
    sleep .2
    ;;
esac
    done
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:38> filename=/home/revision-6/Videos/betty_boop_a_song_a_day_1936.mkv
/home/revision-6/Videos/betty_boop_is_my_palm_read_1932.mkv
/home/revision-6/Videos/betty_boop_more_pep_1936.mkv
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:39> unset x
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:42> filename=betty_boop_more_pep_1936.mkv 
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:43> echo

+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:44> echo

+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:45> echo 'filename=betty_boop_more_pep_1936.mkv'
filename=betty_boop_more_pep_1936.mkv
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:46> echo

+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:47> echo

+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:49> shortname=betty_boop_more_pep_1936 
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:50> echo 'shortname=betty_boop_more_pep_1936'
shortname=betty_boop_more_pep_1936
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:51> echo

+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:52> echo

+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:54> ext=mkv 
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:55> echo

+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:56> echo

+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:57> echo 'ext=mkv'
ext=mkv
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:62> x=+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:62> find /home/revision-6/video_processing -iname 'betty_boop_more_pep_1936*.mkv'
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:62> x=+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:62> wc -c
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:62> x=63 
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:63> echo

+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:64> echo

+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:65> echo 'x=63'
x=63
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:73> case 63 (0)
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:73> case 63 (*)
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:77> mv betty_boop_more_pep_1936.mkv 63.mkv
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:78> cp betty_boop_more_pep_1936.mkv /home/revision-6/video_processing
cp: cannot stat 'betty_boop_more_pep_1936.mkv': No such file or directory
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:79> sleep .2
    exit 0
+/home/revision-6/bin/cpi:83> exit 0

To me the logic seems valid. Count the number of iterations in target and rename the file BEFORE moving it, but I guess my shell-scripting-fu is not up to the task. Any help would be welcome.

AFAIK just declaring array to be an array doesn't cause array=$(yad ...) to assign newline-separated values to it as array elements (it's still a scalar assignment) - you'd need something more like array=("${(@f)$(yad ...)}")

This may be easier with zshs powerful globbing syntax instead of find and wc. Try this:
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
setopt extendedglob

nextFilename() {
    local fqp=${1:?}
    local -a fileCopies=( ${fqp:r}(_copy<->|).${fqp:e}(#qNn) )
    local latestCopy=${fileCopies[-1]}

    if [[ -z $latestCopy ]]; then
        # no matching files at destination, use original filename
        print -r -- $fqp
    elif [[ $latestCopy == (#b)(*)_copy(<->)(.${fqp:e}) ]]; then
        # matching filename with _copyN, add one to number
        print -r -- ${match[1]}_copy$((${match[2]}+1))${match[3]}
    else
        # only has filename without a copy number, use _copy1
        print -r -- ${fqp:r}_copy1.${fqp:e}
    fi
}

The key statement is this one:
local -a fileCopies=( ${fqp:r}(_copy<->|).${fqp:e}(#qNn) )

It creates a sorted array of filenames from the destination directory that match the pattern based on the source filename.

${fqp:r} - the root of the file path. This has the directory and the leading part of the name, i.e. everything but the extension.
(_copy<->|) - _copyN, or nothing (e.g. fname.ext or fname_copy14.ext). <-> is a glob pattern for any number.
${fqp:e} - the filename extension.
(#qNn) - a set of glob qualifiers that modify the behavior

#q - indicates that this parenthesized expression contains glob qualifiers.
N - allow null glob, so that zero matches will not be an error.
n - turn on NUMERIC_GLOB_SUBST for this expansion, so that the results are sorted numerically. With this option, a set of names like f1 f11 f2 will sort as f1 f2 f11.   Filenames without digits in the same place, like fname.ext and fname_copy1.ext will still sort lexically, but here that's the order we want, so no special handling is required.



With the array sorted, the last value in the array (index -1) will be the filename with the highest number, so we can use that to determine what should happen next. One advantage of using this technique is that it can handle gaps in the numbering; an algorithm based on counting could get tripped up by that.
Using / testing:
>> destDir=./dest
>> ls -l $destDir/*
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  0 Jun 23 07:40 ./dest/filename.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  0 Jun 23 07:40 ./dest/filename_copy1.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  0 Jun 23 07:40 ./dest/filename_copy11.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  0 Jun 23 07:40 ./dest/filename_copy2.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  0 Jun 23 07:40 ./dest/onefile.txt

>> srcFile=./src/filename.txt
>> cp -v $srcFile $(nextFilename $destDir/${srcFile:t})
./src/filename.txt -> ./dest/filename_copy12.txt

>> srcFile=./src/nodestfile.txt
>> cp -v $srcFile $(nextFilename $destDir/${srcFile:t})
./src/nodestfile.txt -> ./dest/nodestfile.txt

>> srcFile=onefile.txt
>> cp -v $srcFile $(nextFilename $destDir/${srcFile:t})
./src/onefile.txt -> ./dest/onefile_copy1.txt


We can use this function to build a script that loops through an array of filenames:
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
setopt extendedglob

#####
local sourceFilePattern='~/src/*.mp4'
vared -eh -p "Source Filename or Pattern > " sourceFilePattern
if ((${ret::=$?})); then
    print "vared returned $ret; exiting ..."
    exit 1
fi
# expand the pattern
local -a sourceFilenames=( ${~sourceFilePattern} )

#####
local destDir='~/dest'
vared -eh -p "Target directory > " destDir
if ((${ret::=$?})); then
    print "vared returned $ret; exiting ..."
    exit 1
fi
# expand '~', '*', etc.
local -a destDirArray=( ${~destDir} )
if ((${#destDirArray} > 1)); then
    print "Found more than one match for directory pattern $destDir"
    print "exiting ..."
    exit 1
fi
destDir=${destDirArray[1]}
if [[ ! -d $destDir ]]; then
    print "Target $destDir does not exist or is not a directory."
    print "exiting ..."
    exit 1
fi

#####
print
print "Source file pattern: ${sourceFilePattern}"
print "Source file count:   ${#sourceFilenames}"
print "Destination:         ${destDir}"
if ! read -q '?proceed (y/n)? '; then
    print;print "exiting ..."
    exit 1
fi
print

#####
nextFilename() {
    # copy from above
}
for src in "${sourceFilenames[@]}"; do
    # use the source file basename to determine the next name
    local dest=$(nextFilename $destDir/${src:t})
    print
    print "Executing: cp -v $src $dest"
    print "  Source directory: ${src:h}"
    print "  Source name:      ${src:t}"
    print "  Target directory: ${dest:h}"
    print "  Target name:      ${dest:t}"
    cp -v "$src" "$dest"
done


(pattern|) is more canonical (and doesn't require extendedglob) than (pattern)(#c0,1)

You may want to add the n qualifier for numeric comparisons when Ordering by name here.

Ahh - good point on (pattern|). I was searching for an equivalent operator to ? in a regex, never thought of the simple trick of or-ing with nothing. You may want to add that to your very useful cheat-sheet here. @StéphaneChazelas

Thanks. Done now.

Just read your response. Wowzers, this is so much more advanced than my meager knowledge can comprehend. I'll chew on this for a few hours then try it on some test files later in the day and let you know how it went. Thanks for the help.

Gairfowl, I'm a little confused here. If I an in source_dir and ask dest it it has any copies, if it returns that it has one file match that would mean I need to rename the file in source_dir as *_copy1.ext and then move or copy it over and all is right and we have achieved world peace. I do not understand why you are adding 1. Could you elaborate, please.

Gairfowl. Curse this damn clinical depression! Even when I'm not experiencing and episode my brain isn't quite up to speed. Dest may have three files - copy1, copy3 and copy 7. My method would name source as copy3 and overwrite existing copy 3. How would I renumber from zero?. No, I haven't tried it yet. Still letting it sink in.

I think you're describing the scenario in the third example, where the only match in the destination directory is onefile.txt. That's handled by the the final else clause in the script, where it adds _copy1 to the name. BUT - I missed your requirement to change the filename in the destination directory AND in the source directory. This code does not change the source filenames, it just copies that file to a new filename in the destination directory.

Gairfowl It is the end result that matters. I have multiple videos spread accross three hdds and I want to consolidate them. If  I have a file that uses h264 for the video and recode a copy of it to h265 then I have two files with the same name but are different internally. Between my clinical depressing and the fact the my A.D.D. meds don't work worth a damn I am sure to get confused and delete the wrong one unless I can see  them together in the same place. (My file manager is set to list view. Icon view drives me crazy. I don't care how we get there.

Gairfowl, Sorry if I'm taking too much of your time. I will be using this script from the command line. Would you mind adding something like vared -p "File to copy" followed by vared -p "Target directory". I tried but got confused by the command part.

Not a problem. I can wait.

Gairfowl I can't find the "copy from above".

Gairfowl. I finally found the part you mentioned, actually put it together properly and even though I've only done limited testing it seems to be working fine. Thank you for your time and patience. This was the most difficult section of a file handling suite I am putting together. It will utilize inotify to

Gairfowl. I finally found the part you mentioned, actually put it together properly and even though I've only done limited testing it seems to be working fine. Thank you for your time and patience. This was the most difficult section of a file handling suite I am putting together. It will utilize inotify to start the process of sorting incoming files - archives to archive folder, etc - video filenames normalized, annoying substrings read from user curated list, recoding and audio notmalization. I could not accomplish it without your valuable input. Thanks again.
